# SSH error kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm having a problem when I ssh into wsl2 from a raspberry pi.

I have rules created on my windows machine to forward the port 2222 to wsl2 and an inbound firewall rule is set up to allow traffic on port 2222.

This is the output of the ssh debug when I run this command

```
ssh riccardoob@[windows ip] -p 2222 -vvv

OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "[domain name]" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to [domain name] [ip] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by [ip] port 2222
```

What is throwing me off is the fact that the connection is correctly established and the server is correctly set up.
I have to specify that I was able to ssh into wsl from the same raspberry but all of a sudden this error starts to show up, unfortunately I can't say for certain what I did since the last successfull connection.

Please ask if more informations are necessary to best debug this issue.

EDIT:
I tried from outside the network wsl is connected to, as suggested by a thread that I found here but I get a similar error:

```
ssh_exchange_error: connection closed by peer
```

Comment: sshd is running in WSL? are you able to do `telnet ip 2222`? the errors says the is no server side sshd response and most probably it's not running. while doing ssh, try see the syslog log messages `/var/log/syslog` if something you can get from there too which can help more on debugging the issue.

Comment: @αғsнιη when running `telnet ip 2222` I get
`Trying 82.60.115.70...\nConnected to ssh.riccardohost.space.\nEscape character is '^]'.\nConnection closed by foreign host.`
I also tailed syslog but nothing came up when issuing `ssh riccardoob@ssh.riccardohost.space -p 2222 -vvv`

Comment: and what about sshd running status in server-side?

Comment: I also checked that and it is running.

Comment: so then your windows doesn't forward the traffic to WSL, if possible restart your windows

Comment: and are you able to ssh from windows to WSL directly?

Comment: @αғsнιη I already restarted windows many times but the problem persists. I tried to ssh into wsl from windows but I get the same error.

Comment: OK, now the problem is on WSL and the sshd running in that, see again in syslog while ssh ing from windows now, restart sshd in WSL and try

Comment: @αғsнιη I don't know what changed but now it works. I hate when this kind of things happen. Thank you for your help.